# Why may @Secured in Grails Spring Security be ignored?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.0.3 and the latest Spring Security Plugin to secure my controllers.

But somehow controllers are not secured.

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

@Secured("ROLE_USER")
class SettingsController extends UtilController {
  def index(){
    render "should not run while not logged in"
  }
}
```

When I am and am not logged in, I see the message. If I inject springSecurityService, it shows the correct logged in status (true/false), so the annotation is just not handled.

I've tried to add "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" requirement and to move annotation to method, it doesn't help.

What could it be related with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Secured` annotation accept list of roles (`String[]`), and I guess you have a problem with converting a string to a array of strings.

Can you try with `@Secured(["ROLE_USER"])`?

Comment: I've tried `@Secured(["ROLE_USER", "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"])`, and simply `@Secured(["ROLE_UNEXISTENT"])`, but it doesn't help. Probably it's not that case.

Comment: Are you sure that didn't configure it to use 'resuestmap' security?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have something other than

```
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
```

In the config file?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my case. Make sure to have the **filterInvocationInterceptor** in your list of grails.plugins.springsecurity.**filterNames** in Config.groovy like in the example:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
   'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'logoutFilter',
   'authenticationProcessingFilter', 'myCustomProcessingFilter',
   'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
   'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor'
]
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that the `@secured` annotation only works for the methods inside the controller not for the class.

Try to use it like this:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

class SettingsController extends UtilController {
  @Secured(["ROLE_USER"])
  def index(){
    render "should not run while not logged in"
  }
}
```

Comment: It works for both, particularly well if you are using a hierarchy like ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER.  The controller level will set the lowest level that can access ANY action, then you can set certain actions to require a higher level.  Or it could be used as an addition kind of operation, like if you have ROLE_USER you can access index, but if you have ROLE_USER AND ROLE_ADMIN you can see adminIndex...